# Manipulate mouse cursor with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a presentation in my University about click-jacking, and i saw a very great example that i wanted to create however i didn't know how. The concept is very hard i think please check this video to understand more:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O83P0umh0b0

Basically, on this video the cursor is manipulated, whenever the user point it to the play button, it will be pointed automatically to an advertisement below.i have tried to look for something similar I couldn't find anything. Please can anyone can provide me an example like this one.

I have tried this code, but as you can see the video, the mouse appear in two places. However, with the code that i tried, it just handle clicks!

```
<div id="firstData">Here is a text first to be hover</div>
<div id="secondData">Here is a text Two</div>


window.addEventListener("click", clickjacking, false);

function clickjacking() {
  document.getElementById('secondData').click();
}
```

Comment: Oh, for the love of God, don't do this. Your presentation is on car-jacking and you want to learn how to hijack the mouse?!

Comment: @ScottMarcus If that is for real, then it is very funny! If it is not, then the comment is even funnier!!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't watch the video but here's something to look at. Note, use mouseover not hover.

```
document.getElementById("firstData").addEventListener("mouseover", clickjacking, false);

document.getElementById("firstData").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    document.getElementById("secondData").style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
});

function clickjacking() {
    document.getElementById("secondData").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```